# GitHub projects "un-clickable" in repo

Tags: github

I have a very strange problem and I cannot get down to the bottom of it. I have pushed some projects to my [Repo](https://github.com/KeilCarpenter/Home-Projects) on GitHub and two of them are black and un-clickable and I have no idea why.

This is the push:

```
C:\Users\keilc\Documents\GitHub\homeprojects [master +0 ~1 -0]> git push origin master
Counting objects: 108, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (105/105), done.
Writing objects: 100% (108/108), 3.71 MiB | 111.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 108 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/KeilCarpenter/Home-Projects.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

What is going on? I have no idea at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are nested git repo whose SHA1 has been recorded as **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** (even though they are not submodules), a [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309).

It means you must have `.git` folder under those two directories in your local machine.

One possible option would be to:

- remove those two folders (followed by a `git add -A ., git commit -m "remove nested git repos"`)
- add them back as submodule: `git submodule add /url/to/rpeo/RectionTester`, then add, commit and push)

From there, a those folders still won't be clickable on GitHub, but at least a `git clone --recursive` of your main repo will be enough to get their content back locally.