# git --recursive doesn't clone submodule

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I learned that to download submodules with main repository we can use `--recursive` option when cloning main repository.

I did the same `git clone --recursive git@github.com:passion/academy.git`

I found that it only create a empty directory of submodule but not downloaded its code.

Do we need to do extra stuff like `git submodule update --init --recursive`  ? If yes then what is the use of `--recursive` flag when cloning main repository ?

Comment: If you are using Git 1.6.5 or later your `git clone --recursive` should do as you are expecting. Are you using earlier than that version? That is a fairly old version but figured worth asking :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a recent enough git, and it *still* does not clone submodules, that means those empty folders are not submodules but **[nested git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33909377/6309)**.

A nested repo is recorded in its parent repo as a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**, but there would not be any `.gitmodules` files associated to it.

> `health-check` seem to be a nested git but not sure when cloning give me `No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path for health-check` .. is it necessary for nested git repos to have entry in .gitmodules ?

If you want your nested git repo to be recognized and managed as a submodule, yes.

As illustrated by [your next question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34410024/6309), it is possible that the lack of path entry in `.gitmodules` for `health-check` prevents `hellospawn` (which seems to be a legit submodule) to be checked out.

Comment: I found that I have two sub-directories one is `hellospawn` which is sub-module for sure (entry in .gitmodules ) and another folder `health-check` ( no entry in .gitmodules ). I suspect that `health-check` is a nested repo instead of 'sub-module' . Assume if this is the case then won't --recursive flag pull 'hellspawn' code ? .. I hope I am able to explain the things.

Comment: @voila yes, `--recursive` should clone `hellospawn` (just to be sure, what version of git are you using, on which OS?)

Comment: @voila also, what is the output of `git ls-tree HEAD hellospawn`

Comment: Git version `git version 2.6.4`  .. I just did a clone of main repo again and last line gave me this `Checking out files: 100% (40517/40517), done.             
No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'health-check'`  . I didn't get anything in `hellspawn`

Comment: @voila that explains `health-check` for sure. What about `git ls-tree HEAD hellospawn`?

Comment: 160000 commit 2e5c9cbd00652268ae3e61cde6705ff39aad9202 ./

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98635/discussion-between-voila-and-vonc).

Comment: @voila ok, so it is a gitlink alright. Maybe it refers to the hellospawn repo in its empty state? Does commit 2e5c9c points to a commit with content?

Comment: @voila so what was the issue with heath-check?

Comment: `health-check` seem to be a nested git but not sure when cloning give me `No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path for health-check` .. is it necessary for nested git repos to have entry in .gitmodules ?

Comment: I have created a new question which explain my current problem in better way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34410024/difference-between-nested-git-repos-and-submodules

Comment: @voila Great! Did you declare the submodule or remove its entry?

Comment: I will go by adding `health-check` to submodule.

Comment: @voila Excellent! No more "`No submodule mapping found`", and the `git clone --recursive` should complete its task.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. A few things to check:

1. Check your **.gitmodules** file:

```
% cat .gitmodules
[submodule "src/mysubmodule"]
    path = src/mysubmodule
    url = myurl/mysubmodule.git
```

2. Check your **.git/config** file and make sure the submodule url listed is the same as in .gitmodules:

```
% cat .git/config
...
[submodule "src/mysubmodule"]
    url = myurl/mysubmodule.git
    active = true
```

3. Finally, check the url and make sure this is the correct url (should be the same as what you type in a "git clone" of that submodule).