# Difference between nested git repos and submodules

Tags: git, github

`git version - 2.6.4`

I have stuck in a situation where I am not able to clone complete repo content using `--recursive` flag.

My main repository have two sub-directory `health-check` and `hellspawn`.

I have created `hellspawn` as submodule and it has its entry in `.gitmodules` file also.

I am not sure what `health-check` is, whether a `submodule` or `nested-git`. 
`health-check` does not have entry in `.gitmodules` which make me thing it might be `nested-git`.

if so , then why am I getting git message when cloning main repository with

```
 admin@admins-MacBook-Pro.local:~/try$git clone --recursive     
 git@github.com:url/mainrepo.git 

 Cloning into 'mainrepo'...
 remote: Counting objects: 28713, done.
 remote: Compressing objects: 100% (613/613), done.
 remote: Total 28713 (delta 363), reused 5 (delta 5), pack-reused 28090
 Receiving objects: 100% (28713/28713), 788.79 MiB | 3.54 MiB/s, done.
 Resolving deltas: 100% (17645/17645), done.
 Checking connectivity... done.
 Checking out files: 100% (40522/40522), done.
 No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'health-check'
```

`

As you can see last line if `health-check` is nested git then why git is checking in `.gitmodules` file ?? 
Due to this error, I am not getting code downloaded even in `hellspawn` which is submodule.

Any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> health-check does not have entry in .gitmodules which make me thing it might be nested-git.

It is a nested git repo.

> if `health-check` is nested git then why git is checking in `.gitmodules` file

Because a nested git repo is recorded as a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** (as a submodule is), which means git checks if that **[special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309)** matches one declared in the `.gitmodules` file (because of the `--recursive` option of `git clone`, asking to clone submodules)

Since that special entry does not match any `.gitmodules` entry path, it fails with that warning.

> Due to this error, I am not getting code downloaded even in hellspawn which is submodule

Two approaches:

1. Get rid of that special entry:
   Try and `git rm --cached health-check` (no trailing '`/`', as I mentioned in "[`git --recursive` doesn't clone submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4185579/6309)"), then add and push, and then try the `git clone --recursive` again
2. Declare the submodule

That is:

```
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.health-check.path health-check
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.health-check.url https://github.com/<auser>/health-check
```

(replace `<auser>` by the actual user managing that repo)

Again, add, push, then try the `git clone --recursive` again.